# Soft clip defined by domain fails in fill between for one of tables

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween, path-clipping

I cannot understand why figure (a) does not display the filled region, while (b) does. 
[image: figure (a) must have filled region also]

PGF reports the following warning:

> Package pgf Warning: fill between skipped: the first input path is empty. on input line 20.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.14} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[try min ticks=6]
      \addplot[blue, name path=A] table{tab1.dat};
      \addplot[red, dashed, name path=B] table{tab2.dat}; 
      \addplot[orange] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=0:10}];
     \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
  ~~%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1.0, xscale=1.0]
     \begin{axis}[try min ticks=6]
       \addplot[blue, name path=A] table{tab3.dat};
       \addplot[red,dashed, name path=B] table{tab2.dat}; 
       \addplot[orange] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=0:10}];
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{}
 \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The tables can be downloaded at 
[tab1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikiclkjdy4soxr2/tab1.dat?dl=0)
[tab2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u7x6i2fim0u7cti/tab2.dat?dl=0)
[tab3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cft6h2i99uoj3ql/tab3.dat?dl=0)

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: `tab3.dat` etc. is missing -- apart from that, nice MWE :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, why are data files missing:)? I linked them at the end.

Comment: Missed that :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea why, but it seems the `soft clip` is sensitive to the scaling (or something). For example, if you remove the first 70 data points of `tab1.dat`, or set `xmin=-28`, it works fine.

None of those are solutions of course, but you can increase the `width` to `8cm`. That works fine here at least.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.14} %% <-- 8cm here
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[try min ticks=6]
      \addplot[blue, name path=A] table{tab1.dat};
      \addplot[red, dashed, name path=B] table{tab2.dat}; 
      \addplot[orange] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=0:10}];
     \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1.0, xscale=1.0]
     \begin{axis}[try min ticks=6]
       \addplot[blue, name path=A] table{tab3.dat};
       \addplot[red,dashed, name path=B] table{tab2.dat}; 
       \addplot[orange] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=0:10}];
     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: I had the same problem today (2017-09-20) and changing the size of the plot helped. I would consider this a bug.

Comment: I tried to **issue the bug** (https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/) but my account seems not to work anymore. Maybe you can issue the bug to the developer.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, I did. You can follow it here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/185/

Answer (score 4):

The [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/185/) was fixed in the just released PGFPlots v1.16.
Thus, your MWE now works as expected.